# How can you create an centered AJAX modal popup whose width is percentage based?

Tags: html, css, ajax

I'm using the following style, on an Ajax modal popup.  The Width is set correctly, but it is aligned on the left side of the screen.  If I set the width to a fixed number, eg 600px, it becomes centered.  Is there a way to do both centered and based on a percentage?

```
.modalPopup {
    background-color:#ffffff;
    border-width:3px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:Gray;
    padding:3px;
    position:relative;
    width:80%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
.modalPopup {
    background:#fff;
    border:3px solid gray;
    padding:3px;
    position:relative;
    width:80%;
    margin: 0 10%; /* percent based margins will do the trick */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up using, but Zoltan showed me the way.  This has allows me to have a scrollbar if needed.

```
.modalPopup {
    background:#fff; 
    border:3px solid gray; 
    padding:3px; 
    position:relative; 
    width: 80%;
    height: 400px;
    margin:0 10%; 
    overflow:auto;
}
```